# Possible to make regular expression with sub-query

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for a bit of javascript code that takes a user's input of a mobile number and in one regular expression, performs the following checks:

1. Starts with 07
2. Contains only numbers, whitespace or dashes
3. Contains exactly 11 numbers

Is this possible to do in just one regular expression and if so, how please?

Comment: Yes it is possible. How the number can be formatted with whitespaces or dashes?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but our user's sometimes put a number as 07123 456789 or 07123-456789 or even 07123 456-789 so I have to cope with all these scenarios all the while making sure the count of the digits is exactly 11

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote please?  I'd be happy to correct if an explanation was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying, but after a good while trying different ideas, I finally found a working "single" regular expression:

```
07((?:\s|-)*\d(?:\s|-)*){9}
```

This make sure that it starts with 07, only contains digits, whitespace or dashes, and only 11 of them (9 plus the first 2) are numbers.

Sorry to have wasted your time.

Explanation:

```
()   - include in capture    
(?:) - do not include in capture
\s   - whitespace
|    - or
-    - dash
*    - zero or more
\d   - digits only
{9}  - exactly nine of what is captured
```

Comment: This fails on '07-12345678' but perhaps you users don't use that format ?

Comment: Excellent point HBP!  I have updated the answer to cater for that circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with one regex, but it is possible by testing for two conditions:

```
if(/^07[\d\- ]+$/.test(str) && str.replace(/[^\d]/g, "").length === 11) {
   //string matches conditions
}
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `^`: Anchor that means "match start of string".
- `07`: Match the string `07`. Together with the above, it means that the string must start with `07`.
- `[`: Beginning of a character class i.e., a set of characters that we want to allow
- `\d`: Match a digit (equivalent to `0-9`).
- `\-`:
- " ": Match whitespace (markdown doesn't let me show a single space as code)
- `]`: End of character class.
- `+`: One or more of the previous.
- `$`: Anchor that means "match end of string". Together with the `^`, this basically means that this regex must apply to the *entire* string.

So here we check to see that the string matches the general format (starts with `07` and contains only digits, dashes or spaces) and we also make sure that we have 11 numbers in total inside the string. We do this by getting of anything that is not a digit and then checking to see that the length of the string is equal to 11.

Answer (score 0):

Since @Vivin throws out the challenge :

```
 /^07([-\s]*\d){9}[-\s]*$/
```

- `^07` : begin with digits 07
- `(` : start group
- `[-\s]*` : any number of - or whitespace
- `\d` : exactly one digit
- `){9}` : exactly 9 copies of this group (11 digits including 07)
- `[-\s]*` : optional trailing spaces or -
- `$` : end of string

Of course a more useful way might be as follows

```
 if ((telNo = telNo.replace (/[-\s]+/g, '')).match (/^07\d{9}$/)) {
    ....
 }
```

which has the advantage (?) of leaving just the digits in `telNo`